# macOS + Appium : Possible to setup Appium without using Homebrew as version manager? Possible best options

Tags: appium, mobile-automation, mac

Please read my question carefully, do not rush to close this.

I have worked on multiple projects with Appium. But currently my problem statement is :

> **Setup appium without Homebrew**

- I am aware we should not use `sudo` for `node` and `appium` installations
- Also aware apart from Homebrew we have NVM, NPM and PIP
- If anyboady from community already invested time + energy to see pros and cons with comparison. Please guide if you have worked on earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is : Pip

I would say invested measurable amount of efforts & time and its paid off too. I have  chosen to move fwd with pip because -

- Pip is a package-management system written in Python
- Used to install and manage software packages
- The Python Software Foundation recommends using pip for installing
  Python applications and its dependencies during deployment
- The `pip install <package>` command always looks for the latest version of the package and installs it
- Most importantly fulfilled security concern too